# Plink SVN username issue

Tags: svn, plink

Because Idea threw away its bundled SVN client in recent version I have to configure SVN manually. After few hours of investigation I got it working:

TortoisePlink 64bit, pageant from putty 64bit

```
SVN_SSH=c:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe -i svn-key-private.openssl
```

I realized that if I pass `-I username` then `svn` fails:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://address/opt/svn/repository/trunk'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

If I omit this argument  `svn` works but there is a prompt to enter my username everytime I run it. This is annoying. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not a svn user myself but this got my attention. From what I read on https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/01/2018-1-changes-to-subversion-integration/, it's not that idea is losing svn support. It's just that they are no longer supporting local working copies using version 1.6 and prior.... that means that you could just update to newer local versions (1.7, 1.8, whatever) while still working with a 1.6 (or prior?) svn server. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: They displaced internal SVN library. You need to specify a path to command line SVN binary.